# modprobe vmhgfs gives — FATAL: Module vmhgfs not found

Tags: 14.04, vmware, shared-folders, vmware-player

I'm trying to get shared folders working in VMware Player 6. My host is a Windows 7 box, and the VM guest is Ubuntu 14.x

I'm trying to share an external drive on my Windows machine (`F:`) with my ubuntu guest-vm.

I've reinstalled vmware-tools, and am following this guide. However, when I try `modprobe vmhgfs`, I still just get the error `FATAL: Module vmhgfs not found`.